# Method returning empty list

Tags: python, methods

I was trying to read through a file and and passing the variable to a method. But the method after running the code returns an empty list. Here is my code:

```
import re

sample = open('SampleData.txt')

result=ExtractingData(sample)
print(result)

def ExtractingData(data):
    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip()
        extracteddata = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    return extracteddata
```

Comment: Evidently the last line doesn't contain any data.

Comment: how do i solve it ?

Comment: You need to define the function prior to using it

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you actually care about only last line but this code collects all numbers from file.

```
import re

sample = open('src/ecs.nim')

def ExtractingData(data):
    extracteddata = []
    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip()
        extracteddata.extend(re.findall('[0-9]+', line))
    return extracteddata

result = ExtractingData(sample)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to declare your function before you call it, so you need to write your function call and print statement after the function body.

Looking at the function definition and regex `[0-9]+`, looks like you are trying to get numbers from each line. `re.findall('[0-9]+', line)` would return all numbers from a line as a list, for example`['1', '13', '200']`.

So to get all the numbers in the file, you need to append each of the lines output to a particular list so that you get the list of lists that has numbers from every line, for example `[['10'], ['110'], ['560050', '7596']]`

This code might help you to solve your empty list issue. Make sure your `SampleData.txt` has numbers in it.

```
def ExtractingData(data):
    numbers = []
    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip()
        extracteddata = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
        numbers.append(extracteddata)
return numbers

result = ExtractingData(sample)
print(result)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `result = ExtractingData(sample.readlines())` ?

Comment: The Vaiable sample would be an object of io Wrapper. A loop on that would give us line by line as same as sample.readlines()